# Chrome developer tool shows background color #f6f6f6 but when I hover its different

Tags: css

I am having trouble finding where the background of this [menu](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/learning/sample-page/) is coming from.When I click hover state, background is:

```
background-color: #f6f6f6;
```

but when I hover on the menu, green background is shown. Please guide me where is the green background coming from since I am unable to find it using Chrome developer tools. Thanks.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: I assume you misread my question.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking at the wrong element.

When the `li` is hovered, the `a` changes its background color:

[image]